# Change the name of elements in the batch when exporting from Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, export, batch-processing

What is the way to change the names of the elements in the batch when exporting from Inkscape? Right now I am getting `g` + numbers instead of names. I mean the names like `g123`, `g124` and so on. And what I would like to get is `myName1`, `myName2` and so on.

Comment: I don't know an Inkscape solution. I either rename them by Bash: 'n=100; for f in g*.png ; do mv $f f-$n.png; ((n+=1)); done' (starting at 100, to have names of identical length, works for up to 900 files) but in Thunar, you may mass-rename too (select the files, rename g to myName in the rename dialog which is shown for more than one File. Renaming the groups in the SVG with sed or xmlstarlet would work too and being stable, if you need to change some things later and redo the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `svg:g id` element defines a group. So, you can use the XML Editor to change the ID name.

1. Select the group
2. Click on the XML Editor Icon
3. Select the ID
4. Type a new name
5. Press CTRL+Enter to commit the changes.

[image]

Comment: Everything works. Thank you very much. How could I delete the property if I accidentally created one? For [example](https://imgur.com/a/g7XIU).

Comment: No, I was wrong. You solution does not work. When exporting the batch I am able to change the name of only one object and only manually. It is not a solution. You can see it [here](https://imgur.com/a/ssDql).

Comment: How did you select your objects before renaming? Were they in one group?

Comment: Oh! So in your method I should change id of every group manually? If it is so, then your method is no better than renaming every group while exporting it.

Comment: And still is it possible to make an automatic naming?